# Can't find ApplicationDbContext in DbContextOptions

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am new with .net framework, and i am stuck with this ApplicationDbContext, Here is sample of my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace Rocky.Data
{
public class ProjectDbContext:DbContext
{
    public ProjectDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options): base(options)
    {

    }
}
}
```

Comment: Try this tutorial: to understand the basics: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/intro?view=aspnetcore-5.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is the ApplicationDbContext is not a module it's the class name of the contractor. So replace the ApplicationDbContext with ProjectDbContext. and your problem with be solved.

Here is the code you:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace Rocky.Data
{
public class ProjectDbContext:DbContext
{
    public ProjectDbContext(DbContextOptions<ProjectDbContext> options): base(options)
    {

    }
}
}
```